# VS 2013 WCF Project (VB), seems to drop custom DLL references when I build the project

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I  have a most puzzling problem.  I am experimenting with a WCF project for a little proof of concept exercise in VB. The project contains a very basic GetData implementation.  I now wish to add some new functionality to write a JSON object which the WCF service will receive from Oracle (via UTL_HTTP), back to the Oracle database.  To accomplish the write back to the database I have a tried and trusted 3 tier architecture-based set of DLLs.  I am able to reference these DLLs within the WCF project, and apply the Import statements (Intellisense working as expected), however when I build the project, for some reason the Import statements dont seem to take affect and the project fails to build (intellisense is lost).  The references to the DLLs are still there in the project, like I said, most puzzling... On the other hand might just be a limitation of the WCF project or my lack of experience with this type of VS project.  The following is an excpert of the WCF class in question.

```
Imports Accipiter.PSALERTS2015.BusinessObject
Imports Accipiter.PSALERTS2015.BusinessLogic
Imports Accipiter.PSALERTS2015.DataAccess

Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1
    Private Const _MySql As String = "SELECT * FROM ALARM_REPLAY_NEW where
    alarm_time >= sysdate - (1/24) AND DATASOURCEID IN (3)"
    Private _eventData As DataSet
    Private _eventMngr = New Accipiter.PSALERTS2015.BusinessLogic.ScadaEventManager("PSALERTS", "psalert_admin", "a1ert5")

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetData(ByVal value As String) As String Implements IService1.GetData

    _eventMngr.SQL = _MySql
    _eventData = _eventMngr.GetData()
    Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
End Function

Public Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType Implements IService1.GetDataUsingDataContract
    If composite Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("composite")
    End If
    If composite.BoolValue Then
        composite.StringValue &= "Suffix"
    End If
    Return composite
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Where are the DLL files located? I trust you're not referencing files that exist in the project's own `bin` or `obj` directories?

Comment: Also, what are the error messages you get from the build system, exactly? And what happens if you do a Clean Solution followed by Rebuild Solution?

Comment: Cleaning the solution doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Dai, the compiler responds with the following error message: Error 14 Type 'Accipiter.PSALERTS2015.BusinessLogic.ScadaEventManager' is not defined. d:\users\<...>\JsonWebService\JsonWebSer‌​vice\JsonWebService\Service1.svc.vb 11 30 JsonWebService .The DLLs are pre-built and sourced from an external corporate shared library.

Answer (score -1):

Functionality no longer required.  So removed the problematic code from the project